# Laravel schedule command with cron

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command

I have command `log:demo` and I successfully run it from ssh console with command: `php artisan log:demo`.

Now I need to create cron job and its ok but when cron starts a command I  get in laravel.log:

```
> [2016-03-22 21:45:01] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /home/agroagro/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:283
Stack trace:
#0 /home/agroagro/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(283): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/agroagro/...', 283, Array)
#1 /home/agroagro/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(790): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(Array)
#2 /home/agroagro/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->configureIO(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/agroagro/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/agroagro/public_html/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

Why does manually calling command work, but cron does not?

Comment: Is the cron running for the same user as that's executing it manually? It's a long shot, but you could try to pass a custom `.ini` file  with the setting `register_argc_argv = on` and run the cron job like `php -c /path/custom.ini ...`

Answer (score 2):

does the cron run with the same user and privileges as you do?
is the bash the same? check php version...

that was the problems on my server...